# how to pass commandlinearguments from to a Running Application

Tags: vb.net, menu, command, line, sendto

i'm working on application that gets files names from Sent-To menu and add them to a listbox using this code:

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count - 1

        ListBox1.Items.Add(My.Application.CommandLineArgs(i))

    Next
```

and it works very well when the application is closed and reopen it with a "Send-to" click
but if kept the application running and clicked Send-to Nothing appear
so how to pass command line arguments while the application is running??

Update: my application is single instance so it will not open a new app

Comment: The second time you use Send-To it should open a new app instance.  is yours single instance?

Comment: yes it's a single instance, sorry forgot to mention